# Why are two try-catch blocks required for opening and reading a file?

Tags: java, file-handling

I am trying to read a file but it is asking for two try-catch blocks, one for opening a file and another for reading its content. Why is this required?

```
String line = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("F:\\Mobile Extractor.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please, insert your code in your question

Comment: Please add your code rather than an image. You can do this by pasting it in, be sure to skip one line and to indent all of your code using ctrl + K.

Comment: I have attached an image. i tried uploading the code but it was giving indentation error.

Comment: I have uploaded the code. It is asking to add try-catch block for the while loop also.

Answer (score 0):

The `try-catch` block is required for `IOException`.

It will check for the contents available in the file. If there are no contents, then `IOException` would be thrown else the contents will be displayed.

It should be like:

```
String line = null;
try {
   File file = new File("F:\\Mobile Extractor.txt");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   try {
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) 
        {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
       } catch(IOException ex) 
         {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         }
        reader.close();

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it will throw IO Exception without a try-catch block but why two try-catch blocks are required?

Comment: It won't throw any exception until you add `throws IOException` clause.
One try-catch block is to read the file and another is to check the file's existence

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `finally` block for avoiding memory leaks and closing the streams if you are using versions before 7. From Java 7 on wards you can use try with resources is the best practice

```
String line = null;
File file = new File("F:\\Mobile Extractor.txt");
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
       if(reader!=null){
        reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try-with-Resources:

```
String line = null;
File file = new File("F:\\Mobile Extractor.txt");
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));) {
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The declaration statement appears within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class `BufferedReader`, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Because the `BufferedReader` instance is declared in a `try-with-resource` statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method `BufferedReader.readLine` throwing an `IOException`).

Answer (score 0):

Try java8, you will not require anything. You can simply do it like this.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
    .filter(l -> l.contains(searchWord)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: welcome, functional programming saves you from writing lot of boiler plate code.